# Rewrite that appends a query string is not firing?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to perform internal redirect

From `/search/lalafa` to `/search/lalafa?post_type=review`

The rule is

```
RewriteRule ^/search/([^/]+)$ /search/$1?post_type=review [L]
```

Seems correct but it doesn't seem to be matching:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/?share=c2ce1c7f-60be-40c8-9f0b-58ffc9eeba40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/search/([^/]+)$ /search/$1?post_type=review [L]
> ```

This will fail for two reasons:

1. The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in `.htaccess` does not include the slash prefix, so this rule never matches. It should be `^search/([^/]+)$`.
2. If it did match it would create a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error) since you are rewriting to the same URL-path and not checking the query string.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=post_type=review
RewriteRule ^search/[^/]+$ $0?post_type=review [L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the full URL-path, as matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (NB: no slash prefix). The preceding *condition* checks that the query string is not already equal to `post_type=review`, thus preventing a rewrite-loop.